# sed - what is this curly brace notation called?

Tags: sed, operator-keyword, curly-braces

I just found this:

```
sed '/label/{n;n;s/{}/{some comment}/;}'
```

The intended effect is to seek `label`, proceed 2 lines down (`n;n;`) then substitute in (`s`) `some comment`.

This is an amazing capability I never knew `sed` had.

Would someone be kind enough to specify the name of this curly brace notation, and the name of the class of operators inside the braces?

Comment: Curly braces group commands, `n` and `s` are commands. I don't know of more specific technical terminology, but I recommend [Bruce Barnett's introduction](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-35).

Comment: @Beta thank you. If you'd posted this as an answer I would have accepted it - you were first to respond!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Curly brackets allow to group several commands so that they are executed for the same address range ([reference](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-35)). The thing here is that you specify an address (with one or two line numbers or patterns) and then apply a group of commands to matching lines.

The `n` command is nothing special, and it's documented in `man`, as well as in the linked document. I'm not sure if there's a general name for it.

From `man sed`:

> n N   Read/append the next line of input into the pattern space.

Comment: Excellent linked reference, thank you. Will accept your answer when I can.